# Podcasts App Crashing On Startup

Tags: iphone, podcasts, podcasts.app

I have been using the podcasts app for a while now amd recently(Around a month ago) It started to crash on startup.

Things i've tried:
Deleted all downloaded episodes.
Turned every "automatically" things in settings.
Cleared Cache.
Restarted IPhone.

Phone Specs:
iOS 9.3.3
Iphone 6s

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: Which iOS version?

Comment: iOS 9.3.3 | IPhone 6s

Answer (score 1):

Sure you have solved your problem since August but maybe the solution is going to Settings - Podcasts and turn off Podcasts Sync. Then open the app, check all is ok, and go to Settings to turn on again Podcasts Sync.

Comment: Didn't work, i'll update the thread in a minute.